# Get a particular part of text from output of a command

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a command which gives output a large output with list of some files and other details. The sample output of that command or script is shown below.

```
HOST NAME: ABC.us.XYZ.com
DESCRIBING VIEW: ...
TRANS_STATE: OPEN

ALL AFFECTED FILES:
  1.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/EmailAddressEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  2.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/NationalIdentifierEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  3.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/PhoneEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  4.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/.adf/META-INF/connections.xml 
  5.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/absences/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAbsencesUi.jpr 


CHECKEDOUT RESERVED:
  1.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/.adf/META-INF/connections.xml [edward_view2_brown]
  2.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/absences/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAbsencesUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  3.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/accruals/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAccrualsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  4.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/calendarEvents/ui/xyzAbsMgmtCalendarEventsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  5.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/workSchedules/ui/xyzAbsMgmtWorkSchedsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]


BACKEND BRANCHED ELEMENTS:
================================================================================
abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/EmailAddressEOImpl.java@@/main/st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown/edward_tras1/1
abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/NationalIdentifierEOImpl.java@@/main/st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown/edward_tras1/1
================================================================================
```

I need an output which will be similar to the one shown below. Writing it to the file or removing the numbering will be even more helpful if possible.

```
  1.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/EmailAddressEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  2.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/NationalIdentifierEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  3.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/PhoneEOImpl.java  [MERGE TO BRANCH -> st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown ]
  4.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/.adf/META-INF/connections.xml 
  5.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/absences/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAbsencesUi.jpr 
  1.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/.adf/META-INF/connections.xml [edward_view2_brown]
  2.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/absences/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAbsencesUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  3.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/accruals/ui/xyzAbsMgmtAccrualsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  4.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/calendarEvents/ui/xyzAbsMgmtCalendarEventsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
  5.    abc/xyz/components/xyzCoreSetup/absenceManagement/workSchedules/ui/xyzAbsMgmtWorkSchedsUi.jpr [edward_view2_brown]
abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/EmailAddressEOImpl.java@@/main/st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown/edward_tras1/1
abc/xyz/components/xyzCore/people/core/protectedModel/src/oracle/apps/xyz/people/core/protectedModel/entity/NationalIdentifierEOImpl.java@@/main/st_abc_pt-v2mib/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgold/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzgray/st_abc_pt-v2mibxyzbrown/edward_tras1/1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the lines with `abc/xyz/`, you can pipe from your command into

```
| grep -o 'abc/xyz/.*' > output
```

- `-o` just print the matched part
- `.*` any characters on the line
- `>` send the output to the file `output`

Comment: How to I remove the part in square brackets?

Comment: @AbhishekKothari Assuming the part in square brackets is always at the end of the line, you can use `grep -o 'abc/xyz[^\[]*' > output`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know which directory the files will be in beforehand, you can use the alternative approach of discarding everything that is clearly not a filename:

```
sed '1,/FILES:$/d
     /^$/d
     /^===/d
     /RESERVED:$/d
     /ELEMENTS:/d
     s/^ *[0-9]\+\. *//
     s/ *\[.*//'
```